# Term for the product of two axes?

Tags: terminology, physics, products

I was searching for an unrelated factoid the other day and came across a term which was defined roughly to mean the product of quantities described by two axes. For example, in a distance vs time graph it would be distance x time. It may have been referring to the area under the graph, but it is not the anti-derivative, integral, or Reimann sum. I believe the context was physics-related. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Two possible answers: your "product" could be "held" by a $z$ axis directed by $k=i \times j$ (cross product) where $i$ is for the time dimension and $j$ for the space dimension unless you know sufficiently algebra to use instead an abstract notion which is the exterior product $i \wedge j$.

Comment: Your description is too vague to hope for any sort of definitive answer. There are far too many possibilities. If you could give more details, it might be enough for someone to determine what you are after.